# Enum with funciton as a parameter

Tags: c#, enums, attributes

I need to decorate a large list of enums with a function to use, if it's this enum. I currently have this :

```
public enum AnimalType
{
    [CustomSet(Helpers.ToUpper)]
    Dog,
    Snake,
    Bird
}

public class CustomSet : Attribute
{
    public Func<string, string> Function { get; set; }

    public CustomSet(Func<string, string> function)
    {
        Function = function;
    }

    public string GetFix (string value)
    {
        return Function(value);
    }

}

public static class Helpers
{
    public static string ToUpper(string value)
    {
        return value.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

However, the attribute on the enum gives me an error of

```
Error   CS0181  Attribute constructor parameter 'function' has type 'Func<string, string>', which is not a valid attribute parameter type
```

Which I assume is due to the method not being a native type. Can anyone recommend a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to do with the function?

Comment: In the scenario that I need it for I have around 50 different types of fields, each represented with an enum. Certain fields needs a custom way to correct the value in the field, for instance, pad it with zeros to six chars. In that case, I want to give the enum an attribute of PadLeft(6, '0').

Comment: Have you tried using a dictionary with enum values as keys and `Func`s as values?

Comment: I like that idea! Maybe not decorate the attribute itself, but rather keeping a separate dictionary. I might end up doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Dictionary<AnimalType, Func<string, string>>`:

```
public static readonly Dictionary<AnimalType, Func<string, string>> AnimeTypeMappers = 
    new Dictionary<AnimalType, Func<string, string>>() {
        {AnimalType.Dog, Helpers.ToUpper}
    };
```

Now you can just get the `Func` like this:

```
AnimalTypeMappers[AnimalType.Dog]
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no *clean* way to express a method / delegate in an attribute. One lazy approach might be:

```
[CustomSet(typeof(Helpers), nameof(Helpers.ToUpper))]
```

i.e. a `Type`/`string` pair that you later use to resolve the actual method via reflection. However, I wonder if a better approach might be to make the **attribute itself** the "doer of things", i.e.

```
abstract class FormatAttribute : Attribute {
    public abstract string Format(string value);
}
class UpperCaseAttribute : FormatAttribute {
    public override string Format(string value) => value.ToUpper();
}
```

with:

```
[UpperCase]
Dog,
```

Now, when you use reflection via `GetCustomAttribute` looking for the abstract `FormatAttribute`, you will get the *concrete* instance (in this case: `UpperCaseAttribute`, although you won't know that). Just invoke the `.Format(...)` method on the attribute you get.

Comment: Currently I'm doing other functionality on the enums in this way as well. Ie, create an attrib for each type of fix I want to implement. It works, but most of these fixes Im going to use wont ever be re-used, and I thought being able to specify the method to use in the attrib itself would be ideal, but yeah, I'm starting to lean back/more towards the way that you suggested as well.